# Is there a command line switch for Chrome to disable external protocol handlers (e.g. tel:/)

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I need this when running automated Selenium (Geb) tests. Right now Chrome always pops up a dialog box asking me what to do. I just want it to do nothing instead. Is there such a switch?

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you visit a page and attempt to launch a hyperlink that requires an external protocol handler, the dialog Chrome shows that asks you what to do should also have a checkbox to make it remember your choice.

If you don't see a checkbox or it doesn't work for you, you can try the following after closing all instances of Chrome. Under English language Windows XP edit the file

`%UserProfile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State`

in a text editor. Under English Vista+ the path to the file is

`%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State`.

Now search for a line that says `"mailto": false,` and add your own protocol underneath in a similar manner. For example:

> "mailto": false,
>   **"tel": false,**

If you use some other OS which you failed to specify, search for the file and edit as mentioned above, then open the browser and see if it worked.

Comment: Hi Karan,the problem is when I run an automated test, it is ignoring these settings. That's why I was looking for a command prompt switch.

Comment: Don't think there is one, but I'll get back to you if I find anything.